# Ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z/20\mathbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've seen the very problem asked previously here but I'm here for more of an explanation for what my textbook is doing.

> I am asked to find the number of ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z/20\mathbb Z$.

I've attempted using the fact that homomorphisms "maps the identity to the identity" i.e. for some $\phi :Z/12 \to Z/20$ we have $\phi(1) \to 1$.
...Right?

But my textbook proceed with $\phi(1) = x$ for $x \in Z/12Z$ as if it does not know what $1$, the identity of $Z/12Z$ is going to be mapped to via the homomorphism.
The rest of the proof follows from this assumption, but I'm just baffled with why this is an $x$...I'm just checking, the identity is $e$ such that $\forall a \in S$, a set, such that under the operation defined on $S$, $ae=ea=a$ right?

So under ordinary multiplication, I thought $1$, or technically, the elements of the equivalence class of $1$ are essentially the identity for both rings.

Am I missing something here? Or was it not a necessity that "a ring homomorphism maps the identity to the identity?"
I'm a bit confused here, might be missing something very basic, would be great if someone can clear it up!

Comment: There is no ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$ that preserves identities. So probably your book doesn't require this property for ring homomorphisms.

Comment: Are you sure that they're looking for *ring* homomorphisms as opposed to *group* homomorphisms?

Comment: The problem is that 'ring' in some books means that the multiplication has unit and is commutative, but in some other books not.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for answering! The main reason I assumed it SHOULD send identity to identity is, I had another ring homomorphism problem that assumes that $\phi (1)=1$. The problem was ; Prove that there exists no isomorphism from $Z[ \sqrt{2}] \to Z[ \sqrt{3} ]$. It was built as 1. if $\phi$ is such an isomorphism, then $\phi(1) = 1$ 2. then $\phi(2)= \phi(1+1) = \phi(1) + \phi(1)= 2$. 3. Then $ \phi( \sqrt{2})=x$ implies $\phi(2)=x^2$ but there is no such x in $Z[ \sqrt{3}]$. I understood isomorphisms to be homomorphisms just that it is also bijective..why can this assume $\phi(1) =1$?

Comment: @Melba1993 it can be shown that if $f: R \rightarrow R'$ is a ring isomorphism and $R$ is a unital ring, then $f(1)$ is the multiplicative identity of $R'$. Doesn't your book mention that?

Comment: Actually,...it doesn't :/ Though it did actually says $\phi(1_R)=1_S$ need not necessarily true, but I cannot see the word unital or unitary ring here...I tried to find its definition, but I'm not sure, what are unital rings?

Comment: Right, though the book doesn't mention that....if a unital ring is a ring with multiplicative identity(according to the definition I found), then does it not hold for $Z/12Z$ and $Z/20Z$? $1$ is the multpilicative unit, isn't it?

Comment: @Melba1993 yes, unital rings are those with multiplicative identity. Often authors talk only about unital rings (sometimes even only commutative rings) and do not call them *unital* explicitly. Yes, $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$ are unital rings with $1$ being the identity.

Comment: Right...So, these are unitary and 1 is the unit, then, shouldn't $\phi(1)=1$ and not $\phi(1)=x$ like it has no idea what 1(the identity) is going to be sent to? I see no reason why the homomorphism would not, since they are unitary.

Answer (score 1):

The term *homomorphism* means a lot of stuff in mathematics, but basically it is *a map that preserves structure*. The definition of an abstract ring does not require it to possess a multiplicative identity. So, abstract *ring homomorphisms* are not required to preserve identity (since it can be missing).

On the other hand, the definition of *unital ring* (also *ring with identity*) requires it to have a multiplicative identity; *unital ring homomorphisms* should then preserve it.

Note, that you can consider the same ring as a *unital* one or not, depending on the context (the latter is achieved simply by forgetting the existence of $1$).

Obviously, if the book supposes $\phi(1) = x$, it does not consider *unital rings*, so ring homomorphisms are not required to preserve $1$.

Usually texts on ring theory clearly state what do they call a *ring* and what a *ring homomorphism*.

Comment: Hi, Lisyarus, thanks for taking your time! I just checked my notes, and as you described, it does say "mapping that preserves structure" and mentions nothing about sending 1 to 1...But there's a lemma that says $\phi(0) = 0$ for a ring homomorphism $R \to S$. Also, apparently, $\phi(-x)=- \phi(x)$ as well. I thought I saw somewhere that $\phi(0_R) \to 0_S$ does not necessarily hold but so, just to check, for ALL ring homomorphisms, zeroes are sent to zeroes? Albeit not necessarily the identity?

Comment: @Melba1993 yes, all ring homomorphisms should preserve the additive identity. This can be seen, for example, from the fact that, by definition, a ring is, in particular, an abelian group.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$ that preserves identities.

Indeed, since $12(1+12\mathbb{Z})=0+12\mathbb{Z}$ we would have $12(1+20\mathbb{Z})=0+20\mathbb{Z}$, which is false.

So probably your book doesn't require this property for ring homomorphisms.

If $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring homomorphism (not preserving identities), then $\varphi(1+12\mathbb{Z})$ must be an idempotent of the codomain, so an element $x+20\mathbb{Z}$ such that

1. $x^2-x\in20\mathbb{Z}$
2. $12x\in20\mathbb{Z}$

It's better to first use the second properties, that says $x=5y$ for some $y$. Then we must have
$$
25y^2-5y\in20\mathbb{Z}
$$
so
$$
5y^2-y\in4\mathbb{Z}
$$
In other words, $5y^2-y\equiv0\pmod{4}$, which is the same as $y^2-y\equiv0\pmod{4}$. Then we get $y\equiv0$ or $y\equiv 1$ (modulo $4$).

In the first case we obtain $x\equiv0\pmod{20}$; in the second case $y=4z+1$ and $x=20z+5$. Thus the only possibilities are the zero homomorphism or $\varphi\colon a+12\mathbb{Z}\mapsto 5a+20\mathbb{Z}$.