# Ring homomorphisms definition

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm working on a question where are need to find the number of ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$
The previous question involved finding number of group homomorphisms from $C_n$ to $C_m$, which I think I've managed to do (gcd(m,n)).

In my lecture notes a ring homomorophism is defined as:

'Let $R, S$ be rings. A ring homomorphism φ from R to S is a function φ : R → S such that $φ(1_R) = 1_S$, $φ(r_1r_2) = φ(r_1)φ(r_2)$, and $φ(r_1 +r_2) = φ(r_1)+φ(r_2)$ for all $r_1,r_2 \in R$.'

Wikipedia has the same definition, but when looking at a solution to this problem I found online, they solved it but weren't mapping the identity in $R$ to identity is $S$, and then I read some stuff on this website and people were claiming a ring homomorphism doesn't have to map identity to identity, the problem obviously becomes much simpler if I use my definition, but which one is right? Surely there is only one definition?

Comment: "Surely there is only one definition?" Oh, sweet summer child...

Comment: No, there is surely not only one definition. Not all rings need to have an identity. As for the number of homomorphisms, this has been answered here already, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280415/ring-homomorphisms-from-mathbb-z-12-mathbb-z-to-mathbb-z-20-mathbb-z?rq=1) and in similar posts. Your rings are commutative with $1$, so the lecture notes are right.

Comment: I feel this question must be a duplicate but I'm having trouble finding a good target.  The best I've found is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165503/is-the-zero-map-between-two-arbitrary-rings-a-ring-homomorphism which isn't quite the same question but the accepted answer there answers your question.

Comment: Ahhh I see, so going with my definition, my question is quite simple since the homomorphism is determined by where it maps the identity(since it is the generator of the additive group) as for duplicate, I suppose my primary question was regarding the definition which I didn't realise could be different for different rings, just made an assumption which I've now learned not to make lol